# Problem with web-sharing and resolving localhost

Tags: webserver, web-sharing

I was using `web-sharing` and accessing some webpages that I had developed using `localhost`. I messed up a PostGreSQL installation and deleted anything related to PostGreSQL and in the process appear to have damaged my apache installation.

If I run `ping localhost` the result is

> --- localhost ping statistics --- 794 packets transmitted, 794 packets received, 0.0% packet loss round-trip min/avg/max/stddev =
>   0.033/0.076/0.920/0.055 ms

I then tried running `apachectl configtest` and recieved the following output:

```
Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib   Referenced from: /usr/sbin/httpd
Reason: image not found /usr/sbin/apachectl: line 90: 16227 Trace/BPT trap: 5       $HTTPD -t
```

I also tried

```
curl http://localhost || echo $? curl: (7) couldn't connect to host 7
```

Within `System Preferences->Sharing->Web Sharing` when I try to tick `web-sharing` I end up with it being unticked automatically. I'm fairly sure that my local webserver is not working, but I'm not sure what I can do to fix this problem.

Comment: I've also tried the instructions in this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3243357?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib` show?

Comment: It shows `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  41 Aug 22 09:14 /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib -> /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libpq.5.dylib`

Comment: Aha, broken symlink. Try `ls -l /usr/lib/libpq.*` next.

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   291680 Feb 20  2012 /usr/lib/libpq.5.3.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       41 Aug 22 09:14 /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib -> /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libpq.5.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  1602000 Sep  8  2011 /usr/lib/libpq.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       15 Feb 20  2012 /usr/lib/libpq.dylib -> libpq.5.3.dylib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your feedback in the comments, the installation of PostgreSQL brought its own version of `libpq` (which then got removed during un-install). To fix

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo rm libpq.5.dylib
sudo ln -s libpq.5.3.dylib libpq.5.dylib
```

Then run `apachectl configtest` again to check for further errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ran the above code, and the output from `apachectl configtest` is the following: `httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using celenius.local for ServerName
Syntax OK`

Comment: Disable/enable Web Sharing again then and point your browser to http://localhost/